# Can mmap handle non-contiguous page ranges in a linux driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I'd like to be able to map a single user space address to multiple blocks of low kernel memory.  I have a driver where I allocate multiple 4MB blocks using pci_alloc_consistent().  Ideally, I'd like user space process to see 8MB (i.e. 2 4MB blocks) as a single buffer mapped to its virtual address space.  Is this possible in mmmap()?  Or, is there a way to allocate a chunk of kernel memory greater than 4MB using pci_alloc_consistent() (or other apis as long as memory is dma compatible)?

I'd appreciate any pointers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at function `vm_insert_page()` or `remap_pfn_range()` in *mm/memory.c*.
You can find an example at: *drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-dma-sg.c*, function `vb2_dma_sg_mmap()`

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to accomplish this.  It seems to me that I cannot use remap_pfn_range() because I have to separately allocated buffers via pci_alloc_consistent().  That is, I'm dealing with 2 different virtual/physical addresses.

Comment: vm_insert_page() seems to work but only if I call get_page() on every page chunk of memory allocated via pci_alloc_consistent().  Otherwise only first page works with vm_insert_page().  I'm not quite sure what the consequences are (1280 calls to get_page() for each buffer).

Comment: `vm_insert_page()` inserts one page, so you must do it for every page in your buffer. That is what VB2 DMA sg does. You should you `virt_to_page()` to retrieve a `page` from a virtual address. Internallu, `vm_insert_page()` will do `get_page()` to increase the reference counter

Comment: When I looked at vb2_dma_sg() yesterday it appeared that it did exactly what I was after.  However, I did not pay much attention to how .pages[] were created.  In my case vm_insert_page() was failing because page_count() returned 0 on all pages for a given buffer except for the first one. This is why I needed to call get_page(). Thanks for the pointers.  I'm still trying to assess the cost of this approach. I'll need 180MB worth of buffers (46,080 page entries).  Do you see any potential issues with the approach?

Comment: If you **need** to `mmap` 180MB, then map 180MB. Any other mechanism will be worst because you require `mmap` capability